# Family of irreducible trinomials over finite fields

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields

Is there any "famous" family of  trinomials over finite fields? 
For example over $F_2$ we have

$$
f(x)=x^{2\times 3^k}+x^k+1
$$

Comment: What do you mean by "famous"?

Comment: i mean by famous that is known and particular in a given finite fields

Comment: What is this family's claim to fame? They aren't all irreducible as you [seem to claim](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2546276/11619). OTOH a standard exercise is to show that all the polynomials $$f(x)=x^{2\cdot3^k}+x^{3^k}+1$$ are irreducible over $\Bbb{F}_2$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/70159/11619) for a local solution of that. See also David Speyer's answers for more interesting families. Anyway, I think it was a bit rude to repost at a different site without linking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is famous, but there is a family due to Ore:

$x^q -x - a$ is irreducible over $F_q$ whenever $a \in F_q^\times.$ This is a result of O. Ore,

*Ore, O.*, [**Contributions to the theory of finite fields.**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1989836), Transactions A. M. S. 36, 243-274 (1934). [ZBL60.0111.04](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:60.0111.04).

Comment: I saw this family thank for your answer Professeur, I would like if there is or you have any idea about another family over $F_3$

Comment: Can you please check the result. It is well known that $x^p-x-a$ is irreducible over the prime field. But that result does not work over extension fields. For example over $\Bbb{F}_4$ we have
$$x^4-x-1=(x^2+x+\omega)(x^2+x+\omega^2)$$ with $\omega$ a primitive third root of unity.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, I think $q$ is supposed to be a prime (at variance with the usual notation...)

Comment: Ok. No problem.